# Hide Command Prompt in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, r

I'm trying to run Rscript in Asp.net web Application using Process.start

```
  Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\RScript.exe", @"F:\Project_files\R_script\RandomF_output.R");
```

this command produces correct output, but it shows command prompt in Browser window.
How to hide this command prompt windows from appearing.

Comment: That happens on your server, not the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ProcessStartInfo to start the process and set the CreateNoWindow property to true:

```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\RScript.exe";
   startInfo.Arguments = @"F:\Project_files\R_script\RandomF_output.R";
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   Process.Start(startInfo);
```

You can also set the WindowStyle to ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden